# Помогите выбрать it направление

Tags: python, java, c, avr, iot

я сейчас выбрал два спец.
1.разработчик встраиваемых систем
2 python разработчик ( или java)
Кем работу найти проще и больше зарплаты.И  будет востребован надолго.

Comment: на самом то деле язык программирования почти побоку. А вот понимания алгоритмов (я не говорю о возможности самому написать красно-черное дерево без подсказок или подобное, а просто понимать, как оно работает и почему logn не всегда лучше n), понимания архитектуры и конечно же английский язык.